# put two button on same line

Tags: html, svg, button

I am trying to show two buttons next to each other with SVG's, i have tried the following:

```
<div class='aiti-next-prev' id='aiti_next'><a><STRONG><span>NEXT</span></STRONG><svg class='carousel-cell' viewBox='0 0 300 20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <path d='M8.59 16.34l4.59-4.59-4.59-4.59L10 5.75l6 6-6 6z'/>
    <path d='M0-.25h24v24H0z' fill='none'/>
  </svg></a></div>
<div class='aiti-next-prev' id='aiti_prev' type='button'><a><strong><span>PREV</span></strong><svg class='carousel-cell' viewBox='0 0 300 20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <path d='M15.41 16.09l-4.58-4.59 4.58-4.59L14 5.5l-6 6 6 6z'/>
    <path d='M0-.5h24v24H0z' fill='none'/>
  </svg></a></div>
&gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `viewBox` to `'0 0 24 24'`. Also you need to give a width to `.aiti-next-prev` and `display:inline-block`or float them.

The reason I'm using `viewBox = '0 0 24 24'` is that the svg paths are taking this space. You are using `viewBox='0 0 300 20'`making the svg way to wide (300) leaving you with a lot of white space.

```css
.aiti-next-prev{width:50px;display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class='aiti-next-prev' id='aiti_prev' type='button'>
  <a>
        <strong><span>PREV</span></strong>
        <svg class='carousel-cell' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
          <path d='M15.41 16.09l-4.58-4.59 4.58-4.59L14 5.5l-6 6 6 6z'/>
          <path d='M0,0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/>
      </svg>
  </a>
</div>

<div class='aiti-next-prev' id='aiti_next'>
  <a>
        <STRONG><span>NEXT</span></STRONG>
        <svg class='carousel-cell' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
          <path d='M8.59 16.34l4.59-4.59-4.59-4.59L10 5.75l6 6-6 6z'/>
          <path d='M0,0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/>
        </svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: no it's the same problem u can out the code in this site to see the probem :https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_font_color

Comment: @AbdeEdDerhamAgrawli the link is about the color attribute in HTML5, did you copy the wrong one?

Comment: @AbdeEdDerhamAgrawli - not likely to happen. You're asking people to follow off-site links that support your thoughts (which are different to those providing answers here). YOU are the one that would be interested in doing that - *they're* telling *you* the answer since *they already know* it...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>.aiti-next-prev{display:inline-block}.aiti-next-prev svg{stroke-width:2;fill:none;stroke:black}</style>
<div id='aiti_prev' class='aiti-next-prev'><a><b><span>PREV</span></b><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='carousel-cell' viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
    <path d='M15,5 9,11 15,17'/>
</svg></a></div>
<div id='aiti_next' class='aiti-next-prev'><a><b><span>NEXT</span></b><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' class='carousel-cell' viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
    <path d='M9,5 15,11 9,17'/>
</svg></a></div>
```

Comment: @DerhamAgrawli This is more correct and clean code than previous code.